# Requirements for KDE startup scripts

Tags: kubuntu, scripts, startup, autostart

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10.  I want to include the following startup script for KDE:

```
kstart --desktop 1 firefox
kstart --desktop 2 kmail
kstart --desktop 3 konsole
```

I placed these three commands in a file ~/startup.  I then used System Settings / Startup and Shutdown / Autostart to specify this file as a script, using the Add Script button.  But when I restarted, my system hung -- I couldn't even get the K menu to work.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: The usual - is the script executable ? File manager: right click the script > Properties > Permissions tab:is executable. Second - can you run the script from the konsole ?